# Cannot input entry with variable ENUM (1-9) using web API and Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, postman

I've an entity

```
UpdateStatus
{
   RequestNewId : int
   Status : enum
}
```

> enum Status { Approved = 1, Rejected = 2 }

When I using Postman with body

```
{
   RequestNewId = 123,
   Status : 01
}
```

Everything is work perfect, it mean update status succeed. But when I input the variable **Status = 02**, the entity doesn't have any values, ***it mean the entity is NULL***

And Ofcourse, When I using number 1 - 9, everything is OK.

Please help this case, thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else is wrong, I believe it's because you were calling the web-api via JavaScript, where the numbers has a `0` prefix are octal, hence the strange behavior.

Comment: I don't think so. In this case, the special thing is the reason why when we use **Status = 01** is OK ?